# R: Exporting potentially infinite function outputs to a csv file

Tags: r, function, csv

I have a script that takes raw csv files in a folder, transforms the data in a method described in a function(filename) called "analyze", and spits out values into the console. When I attempt to write.csv these values, it only gives the last value of the function. IF there was a set amount of files per folder I would just do each specific csv file through the program, say [1:5], and lapply/set a matrix into write.csv. However, there is a potential for an infinite amount of files drawn from the directory, so this will not work (I think?). How would I export potentially infinite function outputs to a csv file? I have listed below my final steps after the function definition. It lists all the files in the folder and applys the function "anaylze" to all the files in the folder.

```
filename <- list.files(path = "VCDATA", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
for (f in filename) {
print(f)
analyze(f)
}
```

Best,
Evan

Comment: Maybe `capture.output`? Or `sink`?

Comment: Rather than "potentially infinite outputs", you might want to say "a unknown number of outputs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a reproducible example, but I think you have assign the output of analyze to a  vector or a dataframe (instead of spitting it out to the console).

Something along these lines:

```
filename <- list.files(path = "VCDATA", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
results <- vector() #empty vector

for (f in filename) {
print(f)
results[which(filename==f)] <- analyze(f) #assign output vector
} 

write.csv(results, file=xxx) #write csv file when loop is finished
```

I hope this answers your question, but it really depends on the format of the output of the analyze function.