# python: saving function outputs to csv file

Tags: python, function, export-to-csv

I am having trouble with the following and would very much appreciate your help.

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to run a function I created called ‘get_nav’ which takes inputs ‘Identifiers’ and ‘asofdate’ from a csv file, ‘data’, and queries a third-party API for 3 additional metrics for each identifier as of the given date .

The source file ‘data’ has 31 columns and 49 rows (this will fluctuate over time).  For each row in ‘data’, I need to

1. select the value in the ‘IDnumber’ column and its associated as of date in the ‘Date’ column
2. run the function ‘get_nav’
3. add the results of the query for each line back to the csv file ‘Data’ on correct row
4. save the updated csv file

**The problem:**

Parts 1 and 2 seem to be working as expected.  However, part three is not working – when it does work, only the results for the last IDnumber are saved to the output file.

**What I’ve Tried:**

I have tried using pandas and cvs writer to accomplish this, but each have had different issues and ultimately failed.  I had difficulty iterating over the source file using pandas.

This approach has gotten me the furthest so far and when I print the results in the console, they are accurate – I just need to be able to store/access them.

I think question is similar to mine, but unfortunately I cannot quite translate the answer to my problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718677/12840483

I’ve included samples of my data, my code, and what I would like the output to look like for your reference.

Thank you for taking the time to review.

[image: csv source data]

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def get_nav(identifiers, asofdate):
    
    if not isinstance(identifiers, list):
        identifiers = [identifiers]
        
    
    columns = [
        ["Column", "Expression", "Function", "Parameter", "Display"],
        ["Name",   None,         None,       None,           "Name"],
        ["Height",   None,         None,       None,           "Height"],
        ["Weight",   None,         None,       None,           "Weight"],
        ["Age",   None,         None,       None,           "Age"],
     ]
   
    options={"asof": asofdate}
    
    df = thirdparty.apiquery(ids=identifiers, columns=columns, options=options).as_dataframe()
        
    records = df.to_dict('records')
    return {rec['Name']: rec for rec in records}


data = csv.DictReader(open("data.csv", 'rU'))
for row in data:
    results = get_nav(row['IDnumber'], row['Date'])
    output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
    #sends results to csv file
    output.to_csv(r'F:\backup\holding\Access\Runs\data.csv', index = False)
```

desired output which included the 3 new columns "Height", "Weight", and "Age" and the related data.

[image]

Comment: You assigned the variable `results`, but then you saved `output`. Where did you define `output`?

Comment: Why don't you just return the dataframe from the function, instead of converting it to a dictionary?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Barmar. That was an cut/paste error on my part as I was trying several things to get this to work. I have updated my post to include the output definition. I am relatively knew to Python and still learning my way around, I am not exactly sure how to return the dataframe from the function. I was mainly trying to use other example I came across.